# Expanding args in bash - supplying headers to curl

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a script to submit with curl, and the code I have for the headers doesn't seem to be expanding correctly

```sh
_notify_pagerduty(){
  local routingKey="${1:?You must supply a routing key}"
  local summary="${2:?Please supply the summary}"
  local buildLink="${3:?You must supply a build link}"
  local token="${4:?You must supply and auth token}"
  local endpoint="${5:?You must supply an endpoint to post to}"

  local headers=$(cat <<-EOF
      -H "Content-Type: application/json"
      -H "Accept: application/vnd.pagerduty+json;version=2"
      -H "Authorization: Token token=${token}"
EOF
  )

  local body=$(cat <<EOF
  {
    "routing_key": "${routingKey}",
    "payload": {
        "summary": "${summary}",
        "timestamp": "$(date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z)",
        "source": "blah"
    },
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "${buildLink}",
            "text": "View in Build Pipeline"
        }
    ]
  }
EOF
)

    echo $body | curl -svL -X POST ${headers} "${endpoint}" -d @- 
}
```

Output of headers after above code:

```sh
echo $headers                                                     
      -H "Content-Type: application/json"
      -H "Accept: application/vnd.pagerduty+json;version=2"
      -H "Authorization: Token token=xxxxx"
```

So, looks good

However, when looking at the headers it sent, I get:

```
> POST /v2/change/enqueue HTTP/1.1
> Host: events.pagerduty.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 292
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
```

which generates errors I would expect. I have tried:
`${headers}` and `"${headers}"` and `"${headers[@]}"` and all fail for the same reason

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an array, and use something like `jq` to generate the body.

```
_notify_pagerduty() {
  local routingKey="${1:?You must supply a routing key}"
  local summary="${2:?Please supply the summary}"
  local buildLink="${3:?You must supply a build link}"
  local token="${4:?You must supply and auth token}"
  local endpoint="${5:?You must supply an endpoint to post to}"

  local headers=(
      -H "Content-Type: application/json"
      -H "Accept: application/vnd.pagerduty+json;version=2"
      -H "Authorization: Token token=${token}"
  )

  jq -n --arg rk "$routingKey" \
        --arg summary "$summary" \
        --arg bl "$buildLink" \
       '{ routing_key: $rk,
          payload: {
            summary: $summary,
            timestamp: (now | strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")),
            source: "blah"
          },
          links: [ {
                    href: $bl,
                    text: "View in Build Pipeline"
                   }
                 ]
        }' | curl -svL -X POST "${headers[@]}" "${endpoint}" -d @-
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I can assume `jq` is or will be on the box. If I can, then this is an ideal answer as it achieves my goals and gets rid of funky heredoc format

Comment: Using an array for  the headers is the important part. You can keep `body` as-is as long as it's currently working for you and you are aware of the dangers of defining JSON using string interpolation.

Comment: Your way is def preferred. I would just capture the jq output to a variable for readability sake